# Is it possible create parent child Dockerfile and override the ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I create a DocherFile with OpenJDK base image and run init.sh script.

I want to inherit that Dockerfile and override the init.sh to test.sh script.

Is it possible to "test" docker file inherit from or extends "my-app" docker file and override ENTRYPOINT?

Should I define both "my-app" and "test" dockers in docker-compose?
Can I run only test docker with docker-compose and not both?

My purpose is to run only "my-app" docker in production. But for tests, I want to extend it and run tests and some more configurations.

my-app/Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY initialization.sh /path/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/path/init.sh"]
```

test/Dockerfile:

```
FROM my-app
COPY tset.sh /path/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/path/tset.sh"]
```

Comment: What have you attempted and what errors did you encounter?

Comment: Do you want to run only init.sh for production and only tset.sh for test? Or for test do you want the result of what you ran for production and utilise that for test?

Comment: For production run only init.sh. For test run only test.sh but also add some RUN commands to dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea,

You can have different docker-compose files.

- docker-compose.yml: Contains the definition of all images needed for running your app.

  ```
  my-api:
    image: yourImage
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
  ```
- docker-compose.override.yml: Contains the base config for all images of the previous file.

  ```
   my-api:
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DEBUG 
    ports:
      - "6105:80"
  ```

Using these two files together from CLI

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml
```

This should start your app will all containers and the default environment by default.

**PRODUCTION**

`docker-compose.prod.yml` : This is a replacement of the `docker.override` but contains configurations, environment variables suitable for a production environment.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml
```

**TESTING**
Override the default entrypoint of the image

- `docker-compose-test.override.yml` :

  ```
  app-test:
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "6103:80"
    entrypoint:
        - YourScript
        - memory=1
  ```

Comment: it overrides docker-compose. But is it possible first override Dockerfile?